# How do i make custom api calls in Ant design's filters/Search in a table columns?

Tags: reactjs, django, antd

I have a React application where I'm implementing a filter feature for the columns of my table. The goal is to make the search in the back and get an updated datasource that fit the search criteria or filter criteria. However, I'm facing an issue where the API requests continue endlessly, even after implementing a timeout mechanism.

here is one of the columns :

```
    {
      title: "Project visibility",
      dataIndex: "projectVisibility",
      filters: filterLists.projectVisibilityFilters,
      onFilter: (value) => {
        console.log("onfilter method", value);
        dispatch(setColumnSearchValues("projectVisibility", "filter", value));

        if (timeoutId > 500) {
          clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        } else {
          console.log("how many times i am in the else !!");
          timeoutId = setTimeout(
            dispatch(
              RequestSearchColumns(
                advancedSearchForm,
                quickFiltersForm,
                columnsFiltersForm,
                currentPage,
                pageSize
              )
            ),
            500
          );
        }

        console.log("time taken to reach the back !!", timeoutId);
      },

      onFilterDropdownOpenChange: (visible) => {
        if (visible) {
          setTimeout(() => searchInput.current?.select(), 500);
        }
      },

      render: (value, row, index) => {
        isUnavailableValue(value);
        switch (value) {
          case "Confidential":
            return (
              <div className="custom-width-column w-120">
                <div className="blur-layer"></div>
                <Badge color="red" text={value} />
              </div>
            );
          case "Visible":
            return (
              <div className="custom-width-column w-120">
                <div className="blur-layer"></div>
                <Badge color="#52C41A" text={value} />
              </div>
            );
          default:
            if (isUnavailableValue(value)) {
              return unavailableValue(value);
            } else {
              return (
                <div
                  className={
                    row.isConfidential
                      ? "blur-content custom-width-column w-120"
                      : "custom-width-column w-120"
                  }>
                  <div className="blur-layer"></div>
                  <Badge color="grey" text={value} />
                </div>
              );
            }
        }
      },
    },
```

Despite the implementation of the setTimeout function with a 500ms delay, the API requests are still sent continuously, and the console log after the timeout is reached. I suspect that there might be an issue with how I'm using setTimeout and clearTimeout in this scenario.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.